# Primary and foreign key issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i have issue with references

```
ALTER TABLE POZYCJA_FAKTURY
ADD (CONSTRAINT FK_ASD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Pozycji)
references FAKTURA (ID_Pozycji))
Error report -
ORA-02270: niezgodność klucza unikatowego lub głównego dla tej listy kolumn
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view

create table FAKTURA
(
ID_Faktury  number(9)   not null,
ID_Naprawy  number(9)   not null,
ID_Pozycji  number(9)   not null,
ID_Osoby_Pracownik  number(9)   not null,
ID_Osoby_Klient number(9) not null,
NR_Faktury  number(9)   not null,
Data_Faktury    date    not null,

constraint PK_FAKTURA primary key (ID_Faktury)

);

create table POZYCJA_FAKTURY
(
ID_Pozycji number(9) not null,
Ilosc   number(10)  not null,

constraint PK_POZYCJA_FAKTURY primary key (ID_Pozycji)

);


ALTER TABLE POZYCJA_FAKTURY
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FAKTURA_POZYCJA_FAKTURY FOREIGN KEY (ID_Pozycji)
REFERENCES FAKTURA (ID_Pozycji);
```

Have you got any idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the order you are executing your create statements?  Are you trying to create a FK to a table which doesn't exist yet, or the PK hasn't been added?

Comment: This does not feel quite like mysql to me; mysql does not require referenced fields to be primary or even unique, just indexed... and is _number_ a mysql-supported data type? Also, it looks to me like your reference is backwards.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the error code; this is not MySQL it is Oracle; they are different RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a foreign key which points to the `ID_Pozycji` column on the `FAKTURA` table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Pozycji) references FAKTURA (ID_Pozycji)
```

But that's not the key on that table, `ID_Faktury` is:

```
constraint PK_FAKTURA primary key (ID_Faktury)
```

A foreign key has to point to a key on the target table.  For example:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Faktury) references FAKTURA (ID_Faktury)
```

That's how it would identify the record in the target table.  The `ID_Faktury` column identifies a `FAKTURA` record, so any table which needs a foreign key back to `FAKTURA` would need to reference `ID_Faktury` on that table.  (Though the foreign key column itself doesn't need to have the same name, but it's often a good idea just to avoid confusion.)

---

Conversely, it *may* be possible to reference at least a unique column (if not a primary key).  I'm no Oracle expert, but this message at least implies as much:

> A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching **unique *or* primary key constraint** in the referenced table.

While I'd still recommend using the primary key as your reference point from a data modeling perspective, it's possible that your RDBMS may support just adding a foreign key to a unique field.  But first that field on the `FAKTURA` table needs to be unique:

```
CONSTRAINT U_ID_Pozycji UNIQUE (ID_Pozycji)
```